# Exclusive disjunction in terms of conditional

Tags: logic

I have the following doubt. I would say that [image: This is an exclusive disjunction] means "p implies not q".

Though that equivalence seems natural to me, it is not true. Could someone please give me an intuitive explanation of my error?

Comment: A helpful guide is here: http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/30139/how-do-i-check-if-two-logical-expressions-are-equivalent

Answer (score 1):

Follows from their definitions:

```
p XOR q = (p AND not q) OR (not p AND q)

p => not q = (p AND not q) OR (not p)
```

That is, `p => not q` is vacuously true when p is not true, independent of q's value.

Answer (score 1):

Exclusive disjunction means p≡¬q, i.e. p⊃¬q ∧ ¬p⊃q

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helpful! I guess I was missing the second part of the equivalence.